# registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: is not working in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to register a class, UITableViewCell with code given below. I am calling the method in **viewDidLoad**

```
tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SearchResult")
```

But when I try to duque the cell, I get nil cell. This code is being called in my view controller **extension** (extension implementing the protocol of tableview).

```
var cell: UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SearchResult")
```

Error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a NIB(xib) file for tableviewcell?

Comment: where are you calling registerClass?

Comment: `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SearchResult", forIndexPath: indexPath)`

Comment: @IvanLesko - I have updated my question with information where these things are being called.

Answer (score 1):

It's `nil` every time when the table view hasn't yet initialized any cells. Either you check for it being `nil`:

```
var cell: UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SearchResult") ?? UITableViewCell()
```

but this is actually not perfect (btw if you don't know: the `??` is the result of the expression if the first part is `nil`). You should actually use the following which will certainly return a non-nil `UITableViewCell`:

```
var cell: UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SearchResult", forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SearchResult")! as UITableViewCell
```